# how to jump to page of rendered pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, pdfobject

Im using pdfobject along with forcePDFJS which uses pdfjs viewer.js to render pdf's.. Once they are rendered I need to be able to jump to pages without reloading the document.. The documents can be pretty large

I've seen some mentions about using PDFApplicationViewer.pdfview.currentPageNumber. but I haven't seen a good example on how to use it correclty

I've seen two example of using the PDFApplicationViewer
1. PDFApplicationViewer.pdfview.currentPageNumber = pagNum;
2. document.getElementById('mycanvas').contentWindow.PDFApplicationViewer.pdfview.currentPageNumber = pagNum;

Althought the second on make more sense Im not sure where the contentWindow object from the element comes from. Im assuming the pdfobject embeds something that I could get access too but I can't figure it out..

Also, since I couldn't really find alot on this.. Is this even possible..

For time constraint reasons I don't want to have to put together a new viewer using pdfjs.. I like what comes with the viewer.html.. I just need to jump the pages without reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFObject.embed doesn't return any reference So I looked into the pdfObject code to see how it was embedding the pdf..

for this to work there needs to be a iframe.. So when rendering with pdfobject Im using a configureation as follows:

Notice forcePDFJS=true

```
    if(!pageNum)
    pageNum=1;
var options = {
    pdfOpenParams: {
        view: "FitV",
        page: pageNum               
    },
    forcePDFJS: true,
    PDFJS_URL: "../pdfjs/web/viewer.html"
};
```

Here is code that works

```
var pdfviewer = document.getElementById('pdfviewer');//get the viewer element
var contenttag =  pdfviewer.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]//got this from pdfobject code
contenttag.contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = parseInt(pageNum);//change the page
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `pdfviewer` id is not available anymore.

`PDFObject` does return the reference of `iframe` that it creates. I was using basic HTML + JS so I had to save that reference to global `window` object to be able to access it from anywhere in the project.

[image: Code screenshot]

Finally, with the reference we have, we can access the `PDFViewerApplication` object as below and manipulate the PDF:

[image]